# Generator of the abelian Banach algebra $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, banach-algebras

I want to show that the element $\exp( i \pi x)$ of $C([0,1])$ generates the entire algebra. My approach can be sketched as follows :

1. Let $f \in C([0,1])$. We consider the continuous even extension of $f$ given by $\tilde{f} : [-1,1] \to \mathbb{C}$.
2. Uniformly approximate $\tilde{f}$ with even polynomials. This is possible since the even polynomials satisfy the conditions of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem when we consider the algebra to be the algebra of even functions.
3. Even polynomials are twice continuously differentiable and $2$-periodic on the interval $[-1,1]$, so we can uniformly approximate each polynomial with its Fourier series. Since the interval is $[-1,1]$ the Fourier series of an even polynomial is given by $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n e^{ i n \pi x}$.

I am stuck at this point. The definition of a generator requires that we consider the closure of the polynomials of the generator. In this case the terms $\exp( i \pi n x)$ where $n$ is a negative integer are not polynomials.

Am I missing something in the definition of the generator, or am I approaching this problem incorrectly?

Comment: The algebra $C([0,1])$ is a unital Banach-algebra with involution. What is your definition of generation? Can you use the $1$? Can you use the involution?

Comment: I would use not the Weirstrass theorem to do the approximation, but the Stone-Weierstrass theorem.  The polynomials in $e^{i\pi x}$ is your algebra of functions proved dense by the SWT.

Comment: @GEdgar I think he generates the algebra without using adjoints. Then you cannot apply SWT.

Comment: Yes, Yurii is right. I mention the negative integer $e^{i n x}$ because those are the adjoints that should also belong to the subalgebra if I wanted to use SWT.

Comment: @KayleoftheCreeks Interesting problem. I would like to see a more elementary solution.

Comment: This problem is from John B. Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis". It is exercise 17 from chapter 7 section 8. Some of the exercises in the book have had seemingly no elementary solutions, and some of the exercises have even come from published works in the 20th century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathbb T_+\subseteq\mathbb C$ be the upper half of the unit circle in the complex plane, i.e. $$\mathbb T=\{z\in\mathbb C \colon |z|=1,\Im z\geq 0\}.$$ Then $C[0,1]$ is isomorphic to $C(\mathbb T_+)$ and the generator $exp(i\pi x)$ corresponds to the function $f(z)=z$. The element $f$ generates the subalgebra of complex polynomials. Since the complement $\mathbb C\setminus \mathbb T_+$ of the spectrum of $C(\mathbb T_+)$ is connected, every continuous function $g:\mathbb T_+\to
\mathbb C$ can be uniformly approximated with polynomials, by [Mergelyan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem).