# Generator of Banach algebra $C(\partial D )$

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

The following problem is a Exercise 18, section 8, chapter 7 of Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis.

I want to show that Banach algebra $C(\partial D )$ ($\partial D$ the boundary of $D=\{z:|z|\leq1 \}$) does not have a single generator.

> definition of generation:If $\mathcal{A}$ is an abelian algebra, say that $a\in \mathcal{A}$ is generator of  $ \mathcal{A}$ if $\{P(a): P\; \text{is a polynomial}\}$ is dense in $ \mathcal{A}$.

**My Solution**

$C[0,1]$ is isomorphic to $C(\partial D )$ and the  $\exp(i\pi x)$ is a generator of $C[0,1]$.

but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Why is the exponential a generator?

Comment: @Arctic Cha, in Exercise 17, section 8, chapter 7 of Conway's A Course in Functional Analysis. prove that exponential is a generator for $C[0,1]$

Comment: Ok... then the space cannot be isomorphic as banach algebra it thats the case.

Comment: so I can not  how to proceed.

Comment: @Arctic Char. do you have any solution?

Comment: No, $C(\partial D)$ is not isomorphic to $C([0,1])$. It's isomorphic to $\{f\in C(]0,1]): f(1)=f(0)\}$.

Comment: And no, with the definition above that exponential is certainly not a generator of $C([0,1])$. Probably you're misquoting the exercise from the book or leaving something out...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I'm not an expert, but please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2401343/generator-of-the-abelian-banach-algebra-c0-1?rq=1) discussion.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I actually had $\exp(2\pi it)$ in mind, sorry.